# Android build error [Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio]

Tags: android-studio

when I try to build my App , Android studio always show this error,`Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio` , and i am sure that i never change  any settings in AS .
This makes build process stop a long time,before build can proceed.
Give me sone advices, thanks.

Android studio 1.5, mac os x el capiton

[snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgkdt.png)

Comment: I know the exactly reason, just enlarge the android studio memory size and worked fine.